# Pandas import SQL query - keep column type

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have imported into pandas a SQL query by doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pyodbc

con= pyodbc.connect(
'Trusted_Connection=yes', 
driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}',
server = 'SERVER', 
database = 'DATABASE')

Receivables = pd.read_sql_query("select * from receivables",con)
```

Which works fine, but most columns are now of type "object", some has been recognized as float. Is there no method for just keeping the column type from the SQL server, where they are already defined correctly.

Answer (score -1):

try to use read_sql function from pandas.

Comment: I changed the code to     Receivables = pd.read_sql("select * from receivables",con) instead, but that unfortunately does not change the column types, they are still primarily "object"

Comment: try to define columns dtype like this df = pd.read_sql("Select * From Foo", con, dtypes = ({Column_name: str,
                                                      Column_name2:int}))

Comment: That is a possiblity, but then I have to define all columns manually even though they are defined at the source (sql server) already. Is there no way around that?